# Setting a default value for a config defined value?

Tags: module, magento-1, configuration, administration

How can I assign a default value to a config value, which i am defining in a system.xml file? Currently it defaults to 'no', but i want it to default to 'yes'.

Here is my current definition code:

```
<catalog>
            <groups>
                <my_val>
                    <label>My Label</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>160</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <my_inner_val translate='label comment'>
                            <label>Enable seperate cart items</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </my_inner_val>
                    </fields>
                </my_val>
            </groups>
        </catalog>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can easily add default values for all configuration settings in your `config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <default>
        <cms>
            <wysiwyg>
                <enabled>0</enabled>
            </wysiwyg>
        </cms>
    </default>
</config>
```

At the moment I'm unable to map your `system.xml` setting name to the node in the `config.xml`

I would say it is: `catalog/my_val/my_inner_val`, means:

```
<config>
    <default>
        <catalog>
            <my_val>
                <my_inner_val>1</my_inner_val>
            </my_val>
        </catalog>
    </default>
</config>
```

Small tip in the end: Be careful with the `int` settings. Sometimes magento uses `1` and `2` for yes/no, on/off, etc.

Comment: Great this is what i was trying to figure out

Answer (score 3):

You can assign default values from your module's `config.xml`. Define there node with such xpath

```
config/default/catalog/my_val/my_inner_val.
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Default value store wise for custom fields for customer module create account section:

```
<stores>
    <default>
        <customer>
            <create_account>
                <postcode_validation>postcodevalidation-GB</postcode_validation>
                <postcode_format>Accepted Formats:- AA9A 9AA, A9A 9AA, A9 9AA, A99 9AA, AA9 9AA, AA99 9AA</postcode_format>
                <postcode_regexp>([A-Z])([A-Z])([0-9])([A-Z]) ([0-9])([A-Z])([A-Z]),([A-Z])([0-9])([A-Z]) ([0-9])([A-Z])([A-Z]),([A-Z])([0-9]) ([0-9])([A-Z])([A-Z]),([A-Z])([0-9])([0-9]) ([0-9])([A-Z])([A-Z]),([A-Z])([A-Z])([0-9]) ([0-9])([A-Z])([A-Z]),([A-Z])([A-Z])([0-9])([0-9]) ([0-9])([A-Z])([A-Z])</postcode_regexp>
                <postcode_uppercase>1</postcode_uppercase>
            </create_account>
        </customer>
    </default>
</stores>
```